# Find values of x and y such that a trigonometric equation holds.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Ok, I am currently trying to work on finding all real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that the equation

\begin{equation}
\cos(x+y)=\cos x + \cos y
\end{equation}
holds. Here is what I have done so far. The LHS of the latter equation may be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
2\cos^2\Big(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\Big)-1,
\end{equation}
while the RHS can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
2\cos\Big(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\Big)\cos\Big(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\Big).
\end{equation}
This yields the equation
\begin{equation}
2\cos^2\Big(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\Big)-1=2\cos\Big(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\Big)\cos\Big(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\Big)
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
2\cos^2\Big(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\Big)-2\cos\Big(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\Big)\cos\Big(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\Big)-1=0.
\end{equation}
Set $t=\cos\Big(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\Big)$. Then our equation becomes
\begin{equation}
2t^2-2\cos\Big(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\Big)t-1=0.
\end{equation}
Solving for $t$ using the quadratic formula, one gets
\begin{align}
t&=\dfrac{2\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})\pm\sqrt{4\cos^2(\frac{x-y}{2})+8}}{4}\\&=\dfrac{\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})\pm\sqrt{\cos^2(\frac{x-y}{2})+2}}{2}.
\end{align}
I got stucked in that last step. Any suggestions about how to proceed will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: For starters , $(x,y) = ({ \pi \over 4} , { \pi \over 2} ) $ is one of the solutions ,

Comment: When you view this as a quadratic and calculate the determinant, how do you know that the determinant is not negative? The equation \begin{equation}
2t^2-2\cos\Big(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\Big)t-1=0.
\end{equation} is *not* a quadratic but of the form $f^2(x,y)+g(x,y)f(x,y)-1=0$

Comment: @Sukhoi234 I do not think that is right. $\cos 3\pi/4=-\sqrt{2}/2$ and $\cos\pi/4=+\sqrt{2}/2$.

Comment: The equation is easily solved for $\sin$ and $\tan$ but gets complicated for $\cos$. See Sangchul Lee's approach in the duplication post I linked. Solutions lies on "ellipses looking curves" for cosinus when it belongs to lines for sinus and tangent.